# Implicit function theorem- a misunderstanding?

Tags: multivariable-calculus

I have the following claim in my notebook:

If $F(x,y)=0$, and $\frac{\partial F}{\partial y} \neq 0 $ and $\frac{\partial F}{\partial x} \neq 0 $ then:

1. $F$ is not continuously differentiable (i.e.- not in $C^1$) OR
2. If $y=f(x)$ then $f$ is not differentiable.

Would someone explain me the reasoning behind this claim, please? Is it indeed correct?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can take $F(x,y)=x-y$. Then $F(x,y)=0$ is $x=y$, $\partial_x F=1$, $\partial_y F=-1$. The function $F$ is smooth, and $y=f(x)=x$ is smooth.